# OpenGL es 2.0 draw line with red color

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I have shader code like below:

```
static const char s_v_shader[] =
"attribute vec4 vPosition; \n"
"attribute vec2 my_Texcoor;     \n"
"uniform   mat4 u_TransMatrix;   \n"
"varying vec2 vTexcoor;         \n"
"void main() \n"
"{ \n"
"  vTexcoor = my_Texcoor;       \n"
" gl_Position = u_TransMatrix*vPosition; \n"
"} \n";

static const char s_f_shader[] =
"precision mediump float;\n"
"uniform sampler2D my_Sampler;                    \n"
"varying vec2 vTexcoor;                           \n"

"void main() \n"
"{ \n"
" vec4 tex = texture2D(my_Sampler, vTexcoor);    \n"
"  gl_FragColor = tex;                            \n"
//" gl_FragColor = vec4 ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
"} \n";
```

I want to draw line on this texture and fill red color to the line.
I am able to draw the line but color is always black.

Please someone help me to color the line with red or yellow or green.

Comment: Anybody there please? I am stuck completely. Someone can help me please ? I know without help I can't progress

Answer (score 0):

You can not draw to a texture. You may draw to a FBO (frame buffer object) which has an attached texture.

To achieve this you simply need to generate a new frame buffer `GLuint bufferID; glGenFramebuffers(1, &bufferID);` then you need to bind the buffer and attach the texture to it `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, bufferID) glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID, 0)`. Now you can normally draw to this buffer using your commands to draw the line. In this case there is no need to use a texture in the shader at all, you only need to output the color. But this only draws to the texture, if you need to show it then you will need to bind your main buffer and use the shader with the texture and draw a full screen rectangle with the texture you have.

On the other hand if you only want to draw the texture and the line over it then you need 2 draw calls. First draw the texture in the background by drawing a rectangle with the texture in the shader. Then draw a line with a shader that only takes in the color, no textures there.

Comment: Thanks Matic. But in my case texture is used in shader to render camera video. So on top of camera, I need to draw lines and color the lines.

Comment: And that is explained in the second procedure. You need an extra draw call with shaders that do not include the texture.

Comment: Please help me with code snippet Matic. I am completely blocked.

Comment: Kumar, this is already your second question about this same issue and it seems the only effort from your side is "help, help. Help! HELP!!! Anybody there please? I am stuck completely.". In both cases you provided insufficient amount of the code for anyone to see what exactly are you doing or to help you anyway. Already in the previous question I showed you how to inject a color into the shader and how to output that color. Show the shader you are using for the line and show the drawing procedure code as well.

Comment: Sorry Matic. I can post my partial code and explain bit more where I am stuck.

Comment: Matic, I have posted partial code, Sorry I should have done this before...

Answer (score 0):

```
With reference to above shaders, below is the code

vertShaderNum = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
pixelShaderNum = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
CompileShader(s_v_shader, vertShaderNum);
CompileShader(s_f_shader, pixelShaderNum);
programHandle = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(programHandle, vertShaderNum);
glAttachShader(programHandle, pixelShaderNum);
glBindAttribLocation ( programHandle, 0, "vPosition" );
glLinkProgram(programHandle);
glUseProgram(programHandle);

locVertices = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "vPosition");
locTexcoord = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "my_Texcoor");
locTransformMat = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_TransMatrix");
locSampler = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "my_Sampler");

glGenTextures(1, &gTexObj);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTexObj);

const GLfloat vertices[][2] = {
                        { -1.0f, -1.0f},
                        {  1.0f, -1.0f},
                        { -1.0f, 1.0f},
                        {  1.0f,  1.0f}
                };

const GLfloat texcoords[][2] = {
        { 0.0f, 1.0f},
        { 1.0f, 1.0f},
        { 0.0f, 0.0f},
        { 1.0f, 0.0f}
};
GLfloat transformMatrix[16] =
{
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
glUniformMatrix4fv(locTransformMat, 1, GL_FALSE, transformMatrix);
glUniform1i(locSampler, 0);

Now in infinite loop
While(1)
{

glEnableVertexAttribArray(locVertices);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(locTexcoord);

        // set data in the arrays.
        glVertexAttribPointer(locVertices, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &vertices[0][0]);
        glVertexAttribPointer(locTexcoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &texcoords[0][0]);

=========> I am rendering camera video logic......................

float vVertices[] =
        {
                -0.85f, -0.9f, -0.6f, -0.5f,
        };
        glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
        lDrawArrays ( GL_LINES , 0, 2 );
        glLineWidth( width_test );

Till now everything is good. camera Video is rendered on display.
Line is drawn on Video texture.
Now I want to color the line............. I am stuck as there is no API call support to color the line in opengles 2.0....
```

Comment: You need another shader to do so. It should be similar to the one you have but remove the sampler from it and replace it with a vec4 uniform as described in the previous question you asked. No in the code create both of the programs so instead of programHandle you will have textureProgramHandle and lineProgramHandle. Before you start doing calls for the background call glUseProgram(textureProgramHandle); and before you start the lines call glUseProgram(lineProgramHandle);. Note that all uniforms and attributes must be sent to BOTH of the shaders.

Comment: What happens now is you still use the shader for the background which expects a texture and not a solid color.

Comment: @Matic : I created one more shader program. As you suggest I am having similar vertex and fragment shaders, but in fragment shader I replaced sampler with vec4 uniform variable. In while loop after rendering video I am using glUseProgram(lineProgramHandle) but only video streaming frame is displayed(only one frame not continous streaming). I am unable to get control to lineProgramHandle. switching between programs is not working here.

Comment: glGetUniformLocation(lineProgramHandle, "uniformColor"); is failing always.I am creating new prorgam only for fragment shader. Declaration is:    static const char s_f_shader_new[] =
"uniform lowp vec4 uniformColor;\n"
"varying vec2 vTexcoor_new; \n"
"void main() \n"
"{ \n"
"  gl_FragColor = uniformColor;                            \n"
"} \n";

Comment: Ok so the second shader needs to compile fragment shader, then it needs to link the fragment shader and the vertex shader from the previous program. To get the locations/handles you need to use the correct program first. Basically ensure that all the calls related to the second shader are done after that shader is being used.

Comment: @Matic I compiled fragment shader and attached to previous program. But still not seeing the effect. can you share sample code snippet or any code links where similar requirements are implemented.

Comment: @Matic I have texture2D mapped gl_FragColor. After I start using shader program, texture is rendered on display. I want to draw red colored line on texture. I am able to draw the line but unable to color the line in openGLes 2.0. Any reference or help

Comment: My brain has exhausted trying many things but no breakthrough. Someone save me with code to interchange between two shaders program.

Comment: Could you just post the code you are using to draw.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Matic
static const char s_v_shader[] =
"attribute vec4 vPosition; \n"
"attribute vec2 my_Texcoor;     \n"
"uniform   mat4 u_TransMatrix;   \n"
"varying vec2 vTexcoor;         \n"
"void main() \n"
"{ \n"
"  vTexcoor = my_Texcoor;       \n"
" gl_Position = u_TransMatrix*vPosition; \n"
"} \n";
static const char s_f_shader[] =
"precision mediump float;\n"
"uniform lowp vec4 Texture;  \n "
"uniform sampler2D my_Sampler;                    \n"
"varying vec2 vTexcoor;                           \n"

"void main() \n"
"{ \n"
" vec4 tex = texture2D(my_Sampler, vTexcoor);    \n"
"  gl_FragColor = tex;                            \n"
"} \n";
#endif

static const char s_v_shader_new[] =
"attribute vec4 vPosition_new; \n"
"attribute vec2 my_Texcoor_new;     \n"
"uniform   mat4 u_TransMatrix_new;   \n"
"varying vec2 vTexcoor_new;         \n"
"void main() \n"
"{ \n"
"  vTexcoor_new = my_Texcoor_new;       \n"
" gl_Position = u_TransMatrix_new*vPosition_new; \n"
"} \n";


static const char s_f_shader_new[] =
"precision mediump float;\n"
//"uniform sampler2D my_Sampler_new;                    \n"
"uniform lowp vec4 uniformColor;\n"
//"uniform vec4 uniformColor;\n"
"varying vec2 vTexcoor_new;                           \n"

"void main() \n"
"{ \n"
" gl_FragColor = vec4 ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
"} \n";
#endif

const GLfloat vertices[][2] = {
    { -1.0f, -1.0f},
    {  1.0f, -1.0f},
    { -1.0f, 1.0f},
    {  1.0f,  1.0f}
};

const GLfloat texcoords[][2] = {
    { 0.0f, 1.0f},
    { 1.0f, 1.0f},
    { 0.0f, 0.0f},
    { 1.0f, 0.0f}
};

// Triangle Vertex colors.
const GLfloat color[][3] = {
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}
};

// Start with an identity matrix.
GLfloat transformMatrix[16] =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

void LoadShaders_new(const char * vShader, const char * pShader)
{
        vertShaderNum_new = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        pixelShaderNum_new = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
#if 1
        if (CompileShader(vShader, vertShaderNum_new) == 0)
        {
                printf("%d: PS compile failed.\n", __LINE__);
                return;
        }
#endif
        if (CompileShader(pShader, pixelShaderNum_new) == 0)
        {
                printf("%d: VS compile failed.\n", __LINE__);
                return;
        }

        programHandle_new = glCreateProgram();

        glAttachShader(programHandle_new, vertShaderNum_new);
        glAttachShader(programHandle_new, pixelShaderNum_new);

        // Bind vPosition to attribute 0
     //   glBindAttribLocation ( programHandle_new, 0, "vPosition_new" );
#if 1
    glLinkProgram(programHandle_new);
        // Check if linking succeeded.
        GLint linked = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(programHandle_new, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
        if (!linked)
        {
                printf("%d: Link failed.\n", __LINE__);
                // Retrieve error buffer size.
                GLint errorBufSize, errorLength;
                glGetShaderiv(programHandle_new, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &errorBufSize);

                char * infoLog = (char*)malloc(errorBufSize * sizeof (char) + 1);
                if (infoLog)
                {
                        // Retrieve error.
                        glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle_new, errorBufSize, &errorLength, infoLog);
                        infoLog[errorBufSize + 1] = '\0';
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s", infoLog);

                        free(infoLog);
                }

                return;
        }
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
     //   glUseProgram(programHandle_new);
#endif
}



// Wrapper to load vetex and pixel shader.
void LoadShaders(const char * vShader, const char * pShader)
{
    vertShaderNum = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    pixelShaderNum = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    if (CompileShader(vShader, vertShaderNum) == 0)
    {
        printf("%d: PS compile failed.\n", __LINE__);
        return;
    }

    if (CompileShader(pShader, pixelShaderNum) == 0)
    {
        printf("%d: VS compile failed.\n", __LINE__);
        return;
    }

    programHandle = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(programHandle, vertShaderNum);
    glAttachShader(programHandle, pixelShaderNum);

    // Bind vPosition to attribute 0
    glBindAttribLocation ( programHandle, 0, "vPosition" );


    glLinkProgram(programHandle);
    // Check if linking succeeded.
    GLint linked = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
    if (!linked)
    {
        printf("%d: Link failed.\n", __LINE__);
        // Retrieve error buffer size.
        GLint errorBufSize, errorLength;
        glGetShaderiv(programHandle, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &errorBufSize);

        char * infoLog = (char*)malloc(errorBufSize * sizeof (char) + 1);
        if (infoLog)
        {
            // Retrieve error.
            glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, errorBufSize, &errorLength, infoLog);
            infoLog[errorBufSize + 1] = '\0';
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", infoLog);

            free(infoLog);
        }

        return;
    }
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glUseProgram(programHandle);
}


main()

{

LoadShaders(s_v_shader, s_f_shader);
LoadShaders_new(s_v_shader_new, s_f_shader_new);

// Grab location of shader attributes.
    locVertices = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "vPosition");
    //locColors   = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "my_Color");
    locTexcoord = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "my_Texcoor");
    // Transform Matrix is uniform for all vertices here.
    locTransformMat = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_TransMatrix");
    locSampler = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "my_Sampler");

    /* Create the texture. */
    glGenTextures(1, &gTexObj);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTexObj);
    if (gTexObj == 0)
    {
        printf("Could not load the texture \n");
        return -1;
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);    

    glUniformMatrix4fv(locTransformMat, 1, GL_FALSE, transformMatrix);


    glUniform1i(locSampler, 0);


    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


while(1)


{
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(locVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(locTexcoord);

    // set data in the arrays.
    glVertexAttribPointer(locVertices, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &vertices[0][0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(locTexcoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &texcoords[0][0]);

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Render Video logic on Texture <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<



float vVertices[] =
    {
        -0.85f, -0.9f, -0.6f, -0.5f,
    };


    glUseProgram(programHandle_new); >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Video render stops display is not streaming
    glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray (0 );


    glDrawArrays ( GL_LINES , 0, 2 );
    glLineWidth( width_test );


}



}


}
```

Comment: @Matic: Please read the code from main() function. I have two shader programs. Second shader program I am using in while(1) loop.

Comment: @Matic please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: @Matic Did you get chance to look into my code. Can you please provide any link that uses switching shader program. That should be great help to me. Thanks